# Implement Role Based Security in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, role-base-authorization

I am trying to implement Role Based Security in MVC 4. After searching for quiet some time, I am unable to figure out how to do it. I learned MVC 4 has its own SimpleMembership feature, but I am unable to implement this "Not so Simple (for me)" feature.

Kindly provide any examples for how to implement this.